# Sugestão de programa para criação de árvore Html?

Tags: css, html5

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe um programa de alguma espécie ao qual me permita rapidamente criar uma árvore html, como no exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de adicionar junto às tags no gráfico, o nome da classe ou ID's que também sejam filhos de uma determinada tag.
O objetivo disso é observar e calcular melhor a especificidade css do meu site e assim facilitar a criação do site.
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exitem uma infinidade de softwares que podem te ajudar. E a maioria deles tem "mind" no nome...

Aqui tem uma pequena lista.

- [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/)
- [MindNode](https://mindnode.com/)
- [MindJet](https://www.mindjet.com/)
- [MindManager](https://mindmanager.com.br/mindjet/)
- [XMind](https://www.xmind.net/)

Porém nenhum deles é exclusivo para páginas de site html/css, porém vc pode adaptar para vc ter uma visão mais macro do seu sitemap etc.

Veja alguns exemplos de imagens adaptadas para esse uso.

**MindManager**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo de mapa feito para o Bootstrap**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo apenas do CSS feito no XMind**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Artigo da SmashMagazina sobre o assunto é meio antigo, mas pode te interessar. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/starting-out-organized-website-content-planning-the-right-way/

Comment: Nossa eu acho que essas ferramentas vão me ajudar mesmo com o que eu queria. Vou ler o artigo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @FelipeMoreira o artigo eh de 2010 mas pode ter conceitos que ainda são válidos, os mind maps uns são free outros só pra mac vc tem que ver com qual vc adapta melhor boa sorte ai tmj